# FireMonkey: How do I change styleBook's style on all forms runtime?

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey

I have 2 StyleBooks loaded with custom styles and want them to be applied for all forms at once (testing it on windows, Tokyo 10.2.3).

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    StyleBook := StyleBook2;
  end;

  procedure TForm6.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    StyleBook := StyleBook1;
  end;
```

If I set `UseStyleManager=true`, this code doesn't work. If `UseStyleManager=false`, it works but only for 1 form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Application.Components[]` to get access to each form and set its `StyleBook` property. Leave `UseStyleManager = False` for both stylebooks.

Add to the main form:

```
type
  TForm14 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    procedure ChangeApplicationStyle(sb: TStyleBook);
```

and implement:

```
procedure TForm14.ChangeApplicationStyle(sb: TStyleBook);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if Application.Components[i] is TForm then
      TForm(Application.Components[i]).StyleBook := sb;
end;
```

Finally to change, e.g.:

```
procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChangeApplicationStyle(StyleBook1);
end;

procedure TForm14.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChangeApplicationStyle(StyleBook2);
end;
```